# How to retry the first cypress command if later assertions fail

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I am currently trying to build a function to check if a table that i get as an object matches a table in our frontend. I am using the following code to do that.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("DoesTableContain", (tableName, tableData) => {

    cy.wait(500);

    const tableHeaders = tableData.rawTable.shift();
    const tableRows = tableData.rawTable;

        cy.get(`[data-cy='${tableName}']`).within(() => {
            cy.wrap(tableHeaders).each((_, i) => {
                cy.get('tr').eq(0).within(() => {
                    cy.get('th').eq(i).should('contain',  tableHeaders[i]);
                })
            })
            cy.wrap(tableRows).each((_, i) => {
                cy.wrap(tableRows[i]).each((_, y) => {
                    cy.get('tr').eq(i+1).within(() => {
                        cy.get('td').eq(y).should('contain', tableRows[i][y])
                    })
                })
            })
        })
})
```

My problem is that we can enter values in our table which then does refresh the table. Cypress is to fast and already gets the table before it is reloaded. Since as i unterstand it cypress only retries the last command, cypress will only retry the .eq and i would need it to retry the first cy.get.

Comment: why not just add a longer wait? or another wait to you know it's definitely in the state you want it to be?

Comment: Since the the problem is getting the correct command for retry to happen, you should use the `cy.contains('td:nth-child(${y})', tableRows[i][y])` pattern (note, back-ticks for string interpolation in the selector).